# Bizarre file_get_contents() behavior with plain-text files & no extension?

Tags: php, exec, file-get-contents

I've been working on a local app over the last few days and I've noticed that one of my 'exec()' functions to call an external program didn't fire correctly.  Upon further investigation it was obvious that the program did execute, but it quit prematurely as an important line utilizing 'file_get_contents()' didn't retrieve the contents of the file specified.

The file is a plaintext file without an extension.  I'm guessing that 'file_get_contents()' is treating the file as a directory since there is no extension?  It's strange because if I manually execute the same program from a web browser, everything works perfectly.

Here's an example line for clarity -

```
while(file_get_contents('plaintextfile') == "something"){
/// Do This
    }
```

The above works just fine when I visit /program.php from a web browser, but when calling it like this it gives me a file/folder not found error for 'plaintextfile'.

```
exec('php /program.php', $output);

foreach($output as $output){
print $output . "<br>";
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this situation.  I'm really puzzled by this...

Comment: I doubt you have a program.php in your FS root. Try ./program.php (notice the . before the slash)

Comment: Where is the file located relative to that script?

Comment: Oh, I just simplified for this post.  I have the full path in my program, it's /Library/WebServer/Documents/data/bla/bla/etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP as executed from the browser and executed by the command line (in the `exec()` call) may use different php.ini configurations, and may have different file search paths.  The best course of action is to supply the full path to `plaintextfile`.

```
if(!file_get_contents('/path/to/plaintextfile')){
   // file couldn't be read
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow.  I figured the full path was only important to actually execute the program and once php found program.php it would treat it the same regardless of how it was called.  This worked!